# Mobile Navigation stops working after Ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Alright, so I'm having an issue with my mobile navigation opening after loading ajax. The menu works perfect when there is no ajax loading. When the page initially loads, the menu will work, but after clicking a link and loading the new page content, the menu will not open back up when I click it. (There are no errors that appear in console.)

Upon inspecting the html code in browser, I noticed that for some reason **after loading ajax, it will no longer apply the nav-open class to the header when clicking the nav-trigger**, and this is what reveals the navigation.

I have a feeling all I need is to fix something in the javascript but I'm not exactly sure what is causing it to break. (To give some insight into the app.js, its setup to initially run the scripts for the page, then run them again after ajax is loaded. All the scripts are running properly and the pages all run perfectly with the exception of this mobile-nav issue.)

Any help or insight anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Page Template: (content is what gets replaced with ajax)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/n6vo44Re5QaWo8oCKShBs7/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/xps0dil.js"></script>
    <script>
        try {
            Typekit.load({
                async: true
            });
        } catch (e) {}
    </script>

    <script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">


        {% include header.html %}
        <div id="content">

            {{ content }}

        </div>

        {% include social.html %}

    </div>
    {% include footer.html %}

</body>

</html>
```

Navigation HTML:

```
<header class="cd-auto-hide-header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/" class="page-link" title="home"><img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>


    <nav class="cd-primary-nav">
        <div href="#cd-navigation" class="nav-trigger">
            <span class="cd-nav-icon"></span>

            <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
    <circle fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" cx="27" cy="27" r="25" stroke-dasharray="157 157" stroke-dashoffset="157"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
        <div class="cd-navigation-wrapper">
            <ul id="cd-navigation">
                <li><a href="/work" class="page-link" title="work">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services" class="page-link" title="services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/agency" class="page-link" title="agency">Agency</a></li>
                <li><a href="/culture" class="page-link" title="culture">Culture</a></li>
                <li><a href="/blog" class="page-link" title="blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact" class="page-link" title="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

scss:

```
.cd-auto-hide-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: $nav-height;
    background-color: #fff;
    @include clearfix;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    @include transition(transform .5s);

    &.is-hidden {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    @include media($tablet) {
        height: $nav-height;
        padding: 0;
    }
    @include media($desktop) {
        padding: 0 75px;
    }
    @include media($desktop-large) {
        padding: 0 100px;
    }
    @include media($desktop-largest) {
        padding: 0 200px;
    }
    @include media($desktop-super) {
        padding: 0 300px;
    }
    @include media($desktop) {
        height: $nav-height;
    }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo {
    position: absolute;
    @include center(y);
    margin-left: 5%;
    @include media($desktop) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.logo {
    z-index: 0;

    img {
        width: 80px;
    }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo {
    a,
    img {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
    /* vertically align its content */
    span {
        /* vertically align inside parent element */
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    em,
    em::after,
    em::before {
        /* this is the menu icon */
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 22px;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    em {
        /* this is the menu central line */
        margin: 6px auto 14px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    em::after,
    em::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        left: 0;
        transition: transform 0.2s;
    }

    em::before {
        /* this is the menu icon top line */
        transform: translateY(-6px);
    }

    em::after {
        /* this is the menu icon bottom line */
        transform: translateY(6px);
    }
    @include media($desktop) {
        display: none;
    }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger {
    em {
        /* transform menu icon into a 'X' icon */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0);
    }

    em::before {
        /* rotate top line */
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    em::after {
        /* rotate bottom line */
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
.nav-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    right: 5%;
    top: 40px;
    height: 54px;
    width: 54px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* image replacement */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s);
    cursor:pointer;

    .cd-nav-icon {
        /* icon created in CSS */
        position: absolute;
        @include center; // mixin inside partials > _mixins.scss
        width: 22px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;

        &::before,
        &:after {
            /* upper and lower lines of the menu icon */
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: inherit;
            /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
            @include transform(translateZ(0));
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s, width .7s - 0.2s, top .3s);
        }

        &::before {
            @include transform-origin(right top);
            @include transform(translateY(-6px));
        }

        &::after {
            @include transform-origin(right bottom);
            @include transform(translateY(6px));
        }
    }

    .no-touch &:hover .cd-nav-icon::after {
        top: 2px;
    }

    .no-touch &:hover .cd-nav-icon::before {
        top: -2px;
    }

    svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    circle {
        /* circle border animation */
        @include transition(stroke-dashoffset .7s - 0.3s 0s);
    }

    .nav-open & {
        /* rotate trigger when navigation becomes visible */
        @include transform(rotate(360deg));
        background:#92062b;
        @include transition(background .7s);

        .cd-nav-icon::after,
        .cd-nav-icon::before {
            /* animate arrow --> from hamburger to arrow */
            width: 50%;
            @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s, width .7s - 0.2s);
        }

        .cd-nav-icon::before {
            @include transform(rotate(45deg));
        }

        .cd-nav-icon::after {
            @include transform(rotate(-45deg));
        }

        .no-touch &:hover .cd-nav-icon::after,
        .no-touch &:hover .cd-nav-icon::before {
            top: 0;
        }

        circle {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            @include transition(stroke-dashoffset .7s - 0.3s 0.3s);
        }
    }
}
.cd-primary-nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    @include transition(visibility 0s .7s);

    .cd-navigation-wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        z-index:100;
        /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
        @include transform(translateZ(0));
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        @include transform(translateX(100%));
        @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s);
        @include transition-timing-function(cubic-bezier(.82,.01,.77,.78));

        @include media($desktop) {
            height: $nav-height;
            width: 100%;
            @include transform(translateX(100%));
        }

        > ul {
            z-index:1000;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right: 0;
            background: $brand-color;
            height: 100vh;
            padding-top:40px;
            position:absolute;

            a {
                /* target primary-nav links */
                display: inline-block;
                height: 10vh;
                line-height: 2em;
                padding-left: 1em;
                font-size: 2em;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;

                &.active,
                &:hover {
                    color: #101010;
                }
            }
        }
        @include media($desktop) {
            /* vertically align its content */
            display: table;

            > ul {
                /* vertically align inside parent element */
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                /* reset mobile style */
                position: relative;
                width: auto;
                top: 0;
                padding: 0;
                @include clearfix;
                background-color: transparent;
                box-shadow: none;
                height: $nav-height;
                @include transform(translateX(-100%));
                @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s);

                li {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    float: left;

                    &:last-of-type {
                        margin-right: 0;
                    }
                }

                a {
                    /* reset mobile style */
                    display: block;
                    border: 0;
                    height: 50px;
                    line-height: .75em;
                    padding: 20px 20px 0;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #000;
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    font-weight: $nav-font-weight;
                    @include media($desktop-largest) {
                        font-size: 1.4em;
                    }
                    @include media($desktop-super) {
                        font-size: 1.5em;
                    }
                }

                a:hover {
                    color: #000;
                }

                a::after {
                    position: relative;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 50%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 0;
                    height: 2px;
                    content: "";
                    transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
                    background: $dark-gray;
                }

                a:hover::after {
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    .nav-open & {
        visibility: visible;
        @include transition(visibility 0s 0s);

        .cd-navigation-wrapper {
            @include transform(translateX(0));
            @include transition(transform .7s - 0.2s);
            @include transition-timing-function(cubic-bezier(.82,.01,.77,.78));
        }
    }
}

.cd-primary-nav ul:target,
.nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul {
    /*
        show primary nav - mobile only
        :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
    */
    display: block;
    @include media($desktop) {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}



.no-js main {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.no-js .cd-nav {
    position: static;
    visibility: visible;

    .cd-navigation-wrapper {
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 100px 5%;
        @include transform(translateX(0));
    }
}
```

app.js

```
$(function() {
        init = function() {
                runScripts();

            },

            ajaxLoad = function(html) {
                init();

                $("body").scrollTop(0);
            };

        init();

        //Function that loads in the new content
        var load = function(url) {
            $("#content").load(url + " #content");
        };

        $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //Sets variables to be used for url and page name
            var $this = $(this),
                url = $this.attr("href"),
                title = $this.text();

            //Makes entries into browser history
            history.pushState({
                url: url,
                title: title
            }, title, url);

            document.title = title;

            load(url);

        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            console.log("Ajax Loaded");
            ajaxLoad();

        });
        //Enables use of back and forward buttons in browser
        $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
            var state = e.originalEvent.state;
            if (state !== null) {
                document.title = state.title;
                load(state.url);
            } else {
                document.title = title;
                $("#content").empty();
            }
        });

        // Need to reinitialize scripts so they run when page is loaded

        function runScripts() {
            navigation();

            function navigation() {
                console.log("Navigation script running");
                var mainHeader = $('.cd-auto-hide-header'),
                    secondaryNavigation = $('.cd-secondary-nav'),

                    belowNavHeroContent = $('.sub-nav-hero'),
                    headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
                var isLateralNavAnimating = false;

                //set scrolling variables
                var scrolling = false,
                    previousTop = 0,
                    currentTop = 0,
                    scrollDelta = 10,
                    scrollOffset = 0;

                mainHeader.on('click', '.nav-trigger', function(event) {
                    // open primary navigation on mobile
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (!isLateralNavAnimating) {
                        if ($(this).parents('.csstransitions').length >= 0) isLateralNavAnimating = true;


                        mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
                        $('.cd-navigation-wrapper').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
                            //animation is over
                            isLateralNavAnimating = false;
                        });
                    }
                });
                mainHeader.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
                    if (mainHeader.hasClass("nav-open")) {
                        mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
                        isLateralNavAnimating = false;
                    }

                });

                $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                    if (!scrolling && !mainHeader.hasClass("nav-open")) {
                        scrolling = true;
                        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
                        setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250): requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);
                    }
                });

                $(window).on('resize', function() {
                    headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
                });

                function autoHideHeader() {
                    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

                    (belowNavHeroContent.length > 0) ?
                    checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) // secondary navigation below intro
                        : checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop);

                    previousTop = currentTop;
                    scrolling = false;
                };

                function checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop) {
                    //there's no secondary nav or secondary nav is below primary nav
                    if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
                        //if scrolling up...
                        mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                    } else if (currentTop - previousTop > scrollDelta && currentTop > scrollOffset) {
                        //if scrolling down...
                        mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                    }
                };

                function checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) {
                    //secondary nav below intro section - sticky secondary nav
                    var secondaryNavOffsetTop = belowNavHeroContent.offset().top - secondaryNavigation.height() - mainHeader.height();

                    if (previousTop >= currentTop) {
                        //if scrolling up...
                        if (currentTop < secondaryNavOffsetTop) {
                            //secondary nav is not fixed
                            mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                            secondaryNavigation.removeClass('fixed slide-up');
                            belowNavHeroContent.removeClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
                        } else if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
                            //secondary nav is fixed
                            mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                            secondaryNavigation.removeClass('slide-up').addClass('fixed');
                            belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
                        }

                    } else {
                        //if scrolling down...
                        if (currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop + scrollOffset) {
                            //hide primary nav
                            mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                            secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed slide-up');
                            belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
                        } else if (currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop) {
                            //once the secondary nav is fixed, do not hide primary nav if you haven't scrolled more than scrollOffset
                            mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                            secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed').removeClass('slide-up');
                            belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
                        }

                    }
                };
            };
        });
```

Comment: Since you probably replace the mainHeader that has the handler attached to it, try delegating the event handler to the body or a different element that doesn't change. Something like `$("body").on('click', '.nav-trigger', function(event) {...});` Alternatively, reattach the event handler to the mainHeader manually.

Comment: @Shilly Sorry, I should have added the full page HTML, I updated the question to include. The navigation container isn't being replaced when ajax is loaded, so the mainHeader element shouldn't be changing.

Comment: It looks like you're reapplying the same bindings on each ajax load. If you don't reload the navigation, there's no need to rebind events to it. In effect, you're binding the toggle twice, so your navigation will only work after an even number of ajax calls and will not work after an odd number of calls. ***You should only map events to the newly loaded content, not to all page***. Considering your current script, that's not a trivial task.

Comment: If the menu always stays the same and only the content changes, why do you rerun the navigation() function?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for the thorough explanation, had to smack myself on the forehead after that realization. Got it solved quite quickly, you rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shilly and Andrei Gheorghiu I've managed to solve the issue.

Due to the fact that I had my navigation function being run on the initial page load AND being re-run with every ajax load, it was causing the events to being run twice and so it was only working with every other link click. I moved the navigation function outside of the ajax loading script so that it only runs on the initial page load and it is now function properly.